# Plone won't start because of ZopeXMLConfiguratinError

Tags: plone, product, buildout, application-restart

I just added a new product to my Plone5 buildout and it throws the error below, now even if I comment out all the add-ons, I still get this error, and Plone will not start.

```
zope.configuration.xmlconfig.ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/opt/plone/zeocluster/parts/client1/etc/site.zcml", line 16.2-16.23
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.ATContentTypes-2.2.12-py2.7.egg/Products/ATContentTypes/configure.zcml", line 18.2-18.44
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.collection-1.1.6-py2.7.egg/plone/app/collection/configure.zcml", line 9.2-9.45
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.querystring-1.3.15-py2.7.egg/plone/app/querystring/configure.zcml", line 11.2-11.42
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.registry-1.3.12-py2.7.egg/plone/app/registry/configure.zcml", line 12.4-12.34
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.registry-1.3.12-py2.7.egg/plone/app/registry/browser/configure.zcml", line 6.4-6.43
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.z3cform-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/plone/app/z3cform/configure.zcml", line 10.2-10.41
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.widgets-2.0.5-py2.7.egg/plone/app/widgets/configure.zcml", line 12.2-12.41
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-5.0.5-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/configure.zcml", line 108.4-112.10
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/quintagroup.slidertemplates-1.5-py2.7.egg/quintagroup/slidertemplates/configure.zcml", line 7.2-7.32
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/quintagroup.slidertemplates-1.5-py2.7.egg/quintagroup/slidertemplates/browser/configure.zcml", line 24.2-27.6
    KeyError: 'target_collection'
```

Comment: The last line says, the error derives of the add-on "quintagroup.slidertemplates", did you check, if they have an issue-tracker? And are you operating with a fresh DB or on an already existing one, possibly containing borked up leftovers?

Comment: You generally will have better luck asking questions in https://community.plone.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-ran buildout without any add-ons, then re-ran several times, enabling packages one at a time. Not sure how or why, but now it works--even with the slidertemplates packge...still a black box in terms of reasons why the error was thrown in the first place.